# How do I get a "while" code block to stop terminate on its own after reaching the end of a threshold?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a "while" block that will take earnings from $0-$500 and raise them to the power of 2. This is the code I wrote:

```
income = 0:500

while(income < 501)
{
  income = income * income
  
  print(income)
}
```

When I tried to run it, it appeared to do the correct calculations, but then just wouldn't stop and I got rows upon rows of NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA until I forcibly stopped the program. What am I missing?

Comment: You can do `income^2` Or `income*income`. No need of `while` loop.

Comment: The problem is in your while statement. your income is a vector that takes values from 0 to 500. in while if you put a condition on a vector, it will always check only the first element which is 0 in your case. When you square 0, it will always remain 0 in each iteration and while loop will never terminate. pretty easy to fix

Comment: Okay, thanks! But just for future reference  (and because I'm interested in knowing what went wrong), how would I solve this issue if using a while loop in another context?

Comment: So does that mean that I cannot put any condition on a vector? Because when I tried changing it from 1-500, it gave me the same error. What would be the fix if I specifically only want it to go up until 500?

Comment: What does `while(income < 501)` even mean in this case? `income is a vector of the values from 0 to 500. So you want every value in that list to be <500? or just one? Are you trying to iterate over the values in `income`? Because `income` is a vector of the values themselves, if you want indexes, you can use something like `seq_along(income)`. It's really not clear what your desired output is. Maybe try a smaller example and show exactly what you expect to see.

Comment: Again square of 1 will be 1 so loop will never end. If you change it to 2:500, loop will eventually end but the output according to written logic will be square of vector 2:500 until the first element is above 501. what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick Here is a smaller example: 
income = 1:5

while(income < 6)
{
  income = income * income
  
  print(income)
}

The outcome I want to see would look like this:
[1] 1 4 9 16 25

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment , `*` and `^` are vectorized function and you can directly do `income^2` or `income*income` here without any kind of loop.

Having said that if you had to implement this in a `while` loop here is a way :

```
income = 0:500
output <- numeric(length(income))
i <- 1
while(i <= length(income)) {
  output[i] = income[i] * income[i]
  #print(output[i])
  i <- i + 1
}
```

The result is stored in a variable called `output`.